# iTunes Connect Test Flight won't play AdMob Test Ads

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect, testflight

I just double checked in my Xcode Project and the build I uploaded to iTunes Connect has AdMob test ads ON. However, this same build during Test Flight's Internal Testing is not playing the AdMob test ads, it's playing live ads.

How do I make it play AdMob test ads during beta testing?

Comment: Are you creating another request anywhere else in your code? For example, when you load another ad after a user dismisses it?

Comment: I just do iAd/AdMob shared banner mediation. From my Xcode project when I build my app onto the iOS device, Both iAd and AdMob give me test ads. However, with no change in code, when this same project is uploaded to iTunes Connect and i'm currently testing it on Test Flight's Internal Tester, AdMob gives me live ads.  

Does Test Flight, Internal Testing give you AdMob test ads if you use AdMob ?

Answer (score 3):

To get test admob ads, you need to specify test device. otherwise, only in simulator it shows test ads.

To specify test device :

```
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"]; //my iPhone's UDID
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: That's the code I have in my Xcode Project build. But with iTunes Connect Test Flight Internal Testing i still receive Live admob ads.